# function to get percentage in JavaScript and return decimal value

Tags: javascript

I have this JavaScript function (see below). It only return whole number, it only works when I inputted a whole number. But when I inputted decimal value it doesn't work.

What should I do to handle decimal value?

```
function calc()
{
var license=parseInt(document.getElementById("license").value);
var service=parseInt(document.getElementById("service").value);
var amount=parseInt(license)+parseInt(service);

var mult=service*(parseInt(document.getElementById("preterms").value) / 100);
var mult1=service*(parseInt(document.getElementById("blueterms").value) / 100);
var mult2=service*(parseInt(document.getElementById("configterms").value) / 100);

document.getElementById("amount").value = amount;
document.getElementById("pre").value = mult;
document.getElementById("blue").value = mult1;
document.getElementById("config").value = mult2;

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are making all values as integers ...

Comment: Explain doesn't work???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are working with decimal values You need to use [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead of [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

ex:

```
function calc() {
    var license = parseFloat(document.getElementById("license").value);
    var service = parseFloat(document.getElementById("service").value);
    var amount = parseFloat(license) + parseFloat(service);

    var mult = service * (parseFloat(document.getElementById("preterms").value) / 100);
    var mult1 = service * (parseFloat(document.getElementById("blueterms").value) / 100);
    var mult2 = service * (parseFloat(document.getElementById("configterms").value) / 100);

    document.getElementById("amount").value = amount;
    document.getElementById("pre").value = mult;
    document.getElementById("blue").value = mult1;
    document.getElementById("config").value = mult2;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

change `parseInt` to [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), like

```
var license=parseInt(document.getElementById("license").value);
```

to

```
var license=parseFloat(document.getElementById("license").value);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like folks suggested using `parseFloat`.  The next issue you're likely to run into is formatting the output.  You can use `toFixed` to output your percentages with a fixed number of decimals:

```
(12.34567).toFixed(2)
// => "12.35"
```